# Time.sleep() Error

Tags: python

So time.sleep isnt working. i am on python 3.4.3 and i have not had this problem on my computer with 3.6.

This is my code:

```
import calendar

def ProfileCreation():
    Name = input("Name: ")
    print("LOADING...")
    time.sleep(1)
    Age = input("Age: ")
    print("LOADING...")
    time.sleep(1)
    ProfileAns = input("This matches no profiles. Create profile? ")
    if ProfileAns.lower == 'yes':
        print("Creating profile...")
    elif ProfileAns.lower == 'no':
        print("Creating profile anyway...")
    else:
        print("yes or no answer.")
        ProfileCreation()
ProfileCreation()
```

Comment: you need to import time

Answer (score 2):

You might want to `import time` as at the moment `time.sleep(1)` isn't actually defined, just add the import to the top of your code and this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to following:

```
import calendar
import time
def ProfileCreation():
    Name = input("Name: ")
    print("LOADING...")
    time.sleep(1)
    Age = input("Age: ")
    print("LOADING...")
    time.sleep(1)
    ProfileAns = input("This matches no profiles. Create profile? ")
    if ProfileAns.lower == 'yes':
        print("Creating profile...")
    elif ProfileAns.lower == 'no':
        print("Creating profile anyway...")
    else:
        print("yes or no answer.")
        ProfileCreation()
ProfileCreation()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your import statement you have imported calendar you should import time also. sleep is inside time package.
    import calendar
    import time

```
def ProfileCreation():
    Name = input("Name: ")
    print("LOADING...")
    time.sleep(1)
    Age = input("Age: ")
    print("LOADING...")
    time.sleep(1)
    ProfileAns = input("This matches no profiles. Create profile? ")
    if ProfileAns.lower == 'yes':
        print("Creating profile...")
    elif ProfileAns.lower == 'no':
        print("Creating profile anyway...")
    else:
        print("yes or no answer.")
        ProfileCreation()
ProfileCreation()
```